# wordpress cookies wild card

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

wordpress names cookies like

wordpress_logged_in_bbfa5b726c6b7a9cf3cda9370be3ee91

the part after _in is different for every user. Is there a way I can use it with wild card in

```
$_COOKIE["wordpress_logged_in_bbfa5b726c6b7a9cf3cda9370be3ee91"]
```

so something like

```
$_COOKIE["wordpress_logged_in_%"]
```

Comment: Use for what? I don't understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to loop through the entire $_COOKIE array to see if it matches the pattern:

```
$matches = array();
foreach($_COOKIE as $key => $value) {
  if(substr($key, 0, 20) == 'wordpress_logged_in_') {
    $matches[] = $key;
  }
}
//$matches now contains the key of all matching cookies
```